# Rails on Azure app service: "Could not find 'bundler' (2.1.4)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, rubygems, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy my Ruby 2.6.2 with Rails 6.0.3.4 and I'm getting GemNotFoundException with Bundler:

```
 Running bundle check
`find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.1.4) required by your /home/site/wwwroot>/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.1.4`
```

Running 'gem list bundler' on my local machine returns, I remove the defualt version.

```
bundler (2.1.4)
```

I've tried updating gem and it's 3.1.4.

I'm pretty sure I'm correctly pushing it to Azure, as I made a new app service and pushed my Rails app with bundler 2.1.4 and I've tried restarting the VM.

Quite new to Azure, so am pretty stuck on this.

Comment: What does your project's Gemfile look like? You can check out this [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-ruby) to cross-verify your steps.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @user3911483 I think I made a new project in the end. But the usual way to get around this is to check the gemLock file at the bottom, as that'll say what bundler it's using. They've all got to match up for it to work.